# Check whether DFA accepts majority of words less than a cutoff with another DFA

Tags: automata-theory, regular-language

#### Question

Let $M$ be some DFA that reads integers in base $k$. Does there always exist some other DFA $M'$ that also reads integers in base $k$, where $M'(x)$ accepts if and only if $M$ accepts the majority of words less than $x$?

#### Background and motivation

According to the cited paper, the above process works if we replace "majority" with "modulo $p$" for some constant $p$; that is, we can build a second DFA $M'$ where $M'(x)$ accepts if and only if $M$ accepts 0 mod $p$ words less than $x$. However, this is still in some sense a very "regular" task, in the sense that DFAs can calculate the number of 1s in a string mod $p$, so I am curious to see whether it extends to a simple problem that is not "regular" in the same way.

*Lecomte, P. B. A.; Rigo, M.*, [**Numeration systems on a regular language**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002240010014), Theory Comput. Syst. 34, No. 1, 27-44 (2001). [ZBL0969.68095](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0969.68095).

Comment: How do you manage the strings starting with 0?  Presumably you don't intend the interpret the (infinitely many) strings in 0* as all less than 1?

Comment: @NealYoung I'm assuming that $M$ is insensitive to leading 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the language $L$ of numbers whose binary representation starts with 10, except for the powers of 2. So the first few numbers in $L$ are 101, 1001, 1010, 1011, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10100, 10101, 10110, 10111, 100001 etc. It is easy to see that up to $2^n$, $L$ contains $2^{n-1}-n-1$ numbers. So somewhere around $2^n+n$ the shift happens from NoMaj to Maj, and around $2^n-n$ from Maj to NoMaj. Anyhow, as $n$ can look anything in binary, it is easy to show that the pumping lemma does not hold for $L'$.

Comment: Do you mean $L=10\{0,1\}^*1\{0,1\}^*$?

Comment: Yes. $~$ $~$ $ $

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a reference for this, or did you come up with this yourself?

Comment: Here is the reference: 
@MISC {51984,
    TITLE = {Check whether DFA accepts majority of words less than a cutoff with another DFA},
    AUTHOR = {domotorp (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/419/domotorp)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51984 (version: 2022-10-08)},
    EPRINT = {https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51984},
    URL = {https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51984}
}